# Ionic V1 Xcode IOS run error Blank page at launch / Cordova, Ionic run ios : Build Failed

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I have a problem for my IOS running Ionic V1 project.
I use last version of Xcode : V8.3.3
My Ionic CLI is V2.0.0
My Ionic Project is V1.0
My Device Iphone 6 IOS 10.3.2

My app is running fine on browser, and is running fine on emulator ios. Also my app is running fine on android device. Problem comes when I run on IOS device.

Through Xcode, I had many erros with provisionning profiles but now I don't have anymore and I use the Iphone Developer for signing certificate. I have no warning. But when I lanch "Run" command on device through Xcode, the app installs without any warnings and launch a blank screen with no error or output on the output console log of xcode. 
So Xcode running devices gives me a blank app screen with no error.

Through "Ionic Run IOS" or "Ionic Run Ios --device" or "Ionic run ios -l -s --device" I have an error 65 Xcode : build failed with this error :
Check dependencies
signing for "MyApp" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'IOS 10.3'.

I have been looking on the web for days without any issue.
Please would someone help me to make this app working as I can publish it then with no blank screen..

Regards

Comment: I believe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973856/cordova-error-65-when-trying-to-build-app-for-ios