# Why is Ionic ios cordova build failing

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When creating an ios build with the ionic command:
`ionic cordova build ios --prod --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'`

I keep getting the following code signing error:

```
Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'mybundleid' were found:  Xcode
couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'mybundleid'.
Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile.
To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are plenty of good answers (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102979/4553162), my issue was actually because  of an incorrect entry in my `config.xml` file where I was configuring the cordova branch plugin:

```
<branch-config>
    <branch-key value="my-live-key" />
    <uri-scheme value="my-scheme" />
    <link-domain value="myapp.app.link" />
    <ios-team-release value="INCORRECT_APP_PREFIX" />
</branch-config>
```

The `INCORRECT_APP_PREFIX` actually overwrites what you had in your `build.json` and is the source of the code signing error.

By changing it to the correct app prefix, the build completed correctly